# Jest snapshot different when testing through CI vs locally

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've implemented jest snapshot testing, which works great. Only thing I can't solve is that my component is rendering a different snapshot on my CI. My test is:

```
/* eslint-env jest */
/* eslint import/no-extraneous-dependencies: "off" */

import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import Combobox from '../Combobox';

describe('<Combobox />', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Combobox
        items={[]}
        placeholder=""
        valueKey=""
        labelKey=""
      />
    );

    expect(shallowToJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

And the component is:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

export default class Combobox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentValue: null,
    };
    this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
  }

  updateValue(newValue) {
    this.setState({
      currentValue: newValue,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        valueKey={this.props.valueKey}
        labelKey={this.props.labelKey}
        options={this.props.items}
        value={this.state.currentValue}
        onChange={this.updateValue}
      />
    );
  }
}

Combobox.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  placeholder: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  valueKey: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  labelKey: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

I'm using `enzyme` and `enzyme-to-json` to generate the snapshot. The component itself is a wrapper around `react-select`. When testing locally everything is fine, but on my CI it errors with:

```
FAIL  src/components/__tests__/Combobox.test.jsx
  ● <Combobox /> › renders correctly

    Received value does not match the stored snapshot 1.

    - Snapshot
    + Received

    <Select
        // ...
    -   optionComponent={[Function anonymous]}
    +   optionComponent={[Function Constructor]}
        // ...
    -   valueComponent={[Function anonymous]}
    +   valueComponent={[Function Constructor]}
        valueKey="" />

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/__tests__/Combobox.test.jsx:20:82)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

So `optionComponent` and `valueComponent` have different values, compared to my local snapshots. What could be causing this discrepancy between my local and my remote tests?

Comment: At first I though it was a difference in the modules, that remote was installing newer modules, but a `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` didn't change my local snapshot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update** *(3 Oct 2016)*: Jest 16.0 was released [with the fix](http://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/10/03/jest-16.html#snapshot-updates)!

---

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1740) and will be fixed in Jest v16 ([source](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1740#issuecomment-248534154)). Fixed in PR [#1752](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/1752).

There is a problem how Node.js handles function names. It should be OK if you use **the exact same version of Node.js** on local machine and CI.

For your information, the solution in JEST will be to remove the name from the snapshot. It will look like this:

```
optionComponent={[Function]}
```

A trick/hack [pointed](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1740#issuecomment-248247967) in the issue is to wrap the function in an anonymous function:

```
-      onSelect={onSelectHandler}
+      onSelect={(...args) => onSelectHandler(...args)}
```

Unfortunately, this would have to happen in the `react-select` library.

Comment: Ah! I wouldn't have figured that out on my own, thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I was running into issues with my snaps passing locally but not on CircleCI. After making sure my node versions were matching locally and on CI, I was finally able to see the snapshots that were failing that I wasn't able to see before on my local machine.